# Replace multiple characters in C# using .replace without creating a loop

Tags: c#

I need to replace multiple characters in C# using `.replace` without creating a loop resulting in final string of the final character in the loop

**Example code:**

```
string t1="ABCD";
t1.Replace('A','B').Replace('B','C').Replace('C','D').Replace('D','E');
```

**Result:** EEEE

**Expected result:** BCDE

How do I get the expected result, I do this for a large number of characters in a string <=100 so I need a easy way. Can I do it with replace method or is there some other way?

Comment: Think about what is happening at each call to replace, see what string you have at the end of each call. Then you will see why it is behaving that way. Why not just remove 'A' from the front and add 'E' at the end. Just a thought!

Comment: i understand the way it behaves, i want to know if there is some way to overcome that...

Comment: and get the expected result..

Comment: In this particular example, it should work if you just reverse the order of your `Replace(...)` calls.

Comment: @Augustine just for this particular example!

Comment: what if i add .replace('E','A');

Comment: that's how my real code works i just didnt add it here sry...

Comment: that's not gonna work then. you'll have to do something a little more involved like @un-lucky or Bryce Wagner 's answers

Comment: @Augustine Can you explain your comment regarding `.replace('E','A');`? Is your expected result `BCDE` or `BCDA`?. It seems like adding that `replace()` call would change things.

Comment: the result must be the same BCDE since t1="ABCD". I just want one replacement of a single character i don't want the 'replaced character to be replaced again'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going to the answer let me describe what went wrong in your case, Actually the replace operations returns a new instance of the string so after the first replace(`t1.Replace('A','B')` the resulting string becomes `BBCD`(`A` is replaced with `B`) and you are performing the next replace operation in this string, hence every `B` will be replaced with `C`. so before final Replace your input string becomes `DDDD`.

I've a simple solution using LINQ with String.Join, You can take a look into the [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8s4Wi8) here

```
string inputString = "ABCD";
var ReplacedString = String.Join("", inputString.Select(x => x == 'A' ? 'B' : 
                                                    x == 'B' ? 'C' :
                                                    x == 'C' ? 'D' : 
                                                    x == 'D' ? 'E' : 
                                                    x));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write it yourself, probably the simplest way to code it would be with regexes:

```
Regex.Replace(mystring, "[ABCD]", s =>
{
    switch (s)
    {
        case "A": return "B";
        case "B": return "C";
        case "C": return "D";
        case "D": return "E";
        default: return s;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, it should work if you just reverse the order of your Replace(...) calls.

```
string t1="ABCD";
t1.Replace('D','E').Replace('C','D').Replace('B','C').Replace('A','B');
```

Comment: Beat me by about 30 seconds.

Comment: Reversing that works for the specific example, but it obviously won't work if the substitutions form a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string t1 = "ABCD";
var ans = string.Join("", t1.Select(x => x = (char) ((int) x + 1)));
```

This code will give the next character of the string. But the case of the last character of the alphabet which is `z` and `Z` this will gonna fail. Fail means it would not be `a` or `A` instead it will give `{` and `[`. But most of the cases this could be used to get the next character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The answers already posted will solve the immediate example that you give, but you also say that you have to do this for a large number of characters in a string. I may be misunderstanding your requirements, but it sounds like you are just trying to "increment" each letter. That is, `A` becomes `B`, `I` becomes `J`, etc.

If this is the case, a loop (not sure why you want to avoid loops; they seem like the best option here) will be much better than stringing a bunch of replaces together, especially for longer strings.

The below code assumes your only input will be capital latin letters, and for the letter `Z`, I've just wrapped the alphabet, so it will be replaced with `A`.

```
string t1 = "ABCDEFGXYZ";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char character in t1)
{
    if (character == 'Z')
    {
        sb.Append('A');
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append((Char)(Convert.ToUInt16(character) + 1));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

The following code takes input `ABCDEFGXYZ` and outputs `BCDEFGHYZA`. This is extensible to much larger inputs as well.